# Directory paths are being "translated" in docker run call

Tags: java, docker

I am trying to configure a Java application to be able to be built and executed within a Docker container. I'm doing this so that the user does not need to worry about having the Java JDK, or Maven installed in order to build and run it.

The application accepts the following command-line arguments:

```
-s (or --source-dir) <directory path> [required]
-d (or --dest-dir) <directory path> [required]
-l (or --output-lists) [optional]
-i (or --include-source) [optional]
```

I've successfully configured the Dockerfile to build the app and then set up an entry point. I have also provided a bash script that will take care of running the container, and passing user arguments to the Java application.

When I try to run the containerized application with the script, I'm running into a problem where the directory paths I'm specifying are being "translated" into Windows-form paths *within* the container's context.

I'm probably not describing this very well, so examples follow. BTW, I am running this in git bash, running on a Windows 11 PC.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM harbor.hulk.beast-code.com/library/ubi9-0 AS build

# Install Maven (which installs its own Java distribution).
RUN dnf install -y maven.noarch

WORKDIR /app-build

COPY pom.xml .
COPY README.md .

COPY src ./src

# Build and package application.
RUN mvn clean install

FROM harbor.hulk.beast-code.com/library/ubi9-0

# Install JDK and unzip.
RUN dnf install -y java-11-openjdk-devel.x86_64
RUN dnf install -y unzip.x86_64

WORKDIR /app

# Copy zipped application file from build image.
COPY --from=build /app-build/target/*.zip /app/.

# Unzip zip file.
RUN unzip *.zip

# Note: When container is run, volumes must be mounted as follows:
# docker run ... -v <Helm chart directory>:/tmp/inputs -v <output directory>:/tmp/outputs helm-template-scanner ...
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-classpath", "./helm-template-scanner.jar", "com.beastcode.devops.helm.Main"]

CMD ["--source-dir=/tmp/inputs", "--dest-dir=/tmp/outputs"]
```

docker-run.sh:

```
#! bash

show_usage() {
  echo "Usage: $(basename "$0") [-h] -s <helm chart dir> -d <output dir> [-l] [-i]"
  echo "Where:"
  echo "  -h        - Display usage and exit."
  echo "  -s <dir>  - Helm chart directory to scan."
  echo "  -d <dir>  - Output directory."
  echo "  -l        - [optional] Writes lists of definitions and references found to files."
  echo "  -i        - [optional] Includes source line for each referenced line number."
  exit 0
}

while getopts "s: d: l i h" flag
do
  case "${flag}" in
    h) show_usage;;
    s) source_dir=${OPTARG};;
    d) dest_dir=${OPTARG};;
    l) output_lists=true;;
    i) include_source=true;;
    \?) show_usage
        exit 1
  esac
done

echo $source_dir
echo $dest_dir
echo $output_lists
echo $include_source

# Check and validate arguments.

if [ -z $source_dir ]; then
  echo "Missing Helm chart directory"
  show_usage
  exit 1
elif [ ! -d $source_dir ]; then
  echo "Helm chart directory '$source_dir' does not exist"
  show_usage
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z $dest_dir ]; then
  echo "Missing output directory"
  show_usage
  exit 1
elif [ ! -d $dest_dir ]; then
  echo "Output directory '$dest_dir' does not exist"
  show_usage
  exit 1
fi

if [ ! -z $output_lists ]; then
  output_lists_flag="--output-lists"
else
  output_lists_flag=""
fi

if [ ! -z $include_source ]; then
  include_source_flag="--include-source"
else
  include_source_flag=""
fi

# Run Docker container to execute Java application to scan Helm chart templates.
docker run -it --rm -v $source_dir:/tmp/inputs -v $dest_dir:/tmp/outputs helm-template-scanner --source-dir=/tmp/inputs --dest-dir=/tmp/outputs $output_lists_flag $include_source_flag
```

Sample script execution with tracing turned on:

```
$ bash -x ./docker-run.sh -s /c/Users/jgagnon/devops/charts/helm/spoe -d $PWD -i
+ getopts 's: d: l i h' flag
+ case "${flag}" in
+ source_dir=/c/Users/jgagnon/devops/charts/helm/spoe
+ getopts 's: d: l i h' flag
+ case "${flag}" in
+ dest_dir=/c/Users/jgagnon/workspace/devops-util/java/helm-template-scanner
+ getopts 's: d: l i h' flag
+ case "${flag}" in
+ include_source=true
+ getopts 's: d: l i h' flag
+ echo /c/Users/jgagnon/devops/charts/helm/spoe
/c/Users/jgagnon/devops/charts/helm/spoe
+ echo /c/Users/jgagnon/workspace/devops-util/java/helm-template-scanner
/c/Users/jgagnon/workspace/devops-util/java/helm-template-scanner
+ echo

+ echo true
true
+ '[' -z /c/Users/jgagnon/devops/charts/helm/spoe ']'
+ '[' '!' -d /c/Users/jgagnon/devops/charts/helm/spoe ']'
+ '[' -z /c/Users/jgagnon/workspace/devops-util/java/helm-template-scanner ']'
+ '[' '!' -d /c/Users/jgagnon/workspace/devops-util/java/helm-template-scanner ']'
+ '[' '!' -z ']'
+ output_lists_flag=
+ '[' '!' -z true ']'
+ include_source_flag=--include-source
+ docker run -it --rm -v /c/Users/jgagnon/devops/charts/helm/spoe:/tmp/inputs -v /c/Users/jgagnon/workspace/devops-util/java/helm-template-scanner:/tmp/outputs helm-template-scanner --source-dir=/tmp/inputs --dest-dir=/tmp/outputs --include-source
2023-01-09 13:37:23 INFO  Main:22 - Command line arguments:
2023-01-09 13:37:23 INFO  Main:23 - --source-dir=C:/Users/jgagnon/AppData/Local/Temp/inputs
2023-01-09 13:37:23 INFO  Main:23 - --dest-dir=C:/Users/jgagnon/AppData/Local/Temp/outputs
2023-01-09 13:37:23 INFO  Main:23 - --include-source
2023-01-09 13:37:23 ERROR Main:31 - Exception encountered processing CLI arguments
java.lang.RuntimeException: Source directory does not exist or is not readable
        at com.beastcode.devops.helm.CommandLineProcessor.validate(CommandLineProcessor.java:77) ~[helm-template-scanner.jar:?]
        at com.beastcode.devops.helm.CommandLineProcessor.process(CommandLineProcessor.java:63) ~[helm-template-scanner.jar:?]
        at com.beastcode.devops.helm.Main.main(Main.java:29) ~[helm-template-scanner.jar:?]
usage: helm-template-scanner -d <arg> [-i] [-l] -s <arg>
 -d,--dest-dir <arg>     Output destination directory
 -i,--include-source     Include source line for each reference
 -l,--output-lists       Output definitions and references lists
 -s,--source-dir <arg>   Helm chart directory
```

Note that the source and dest dir paths have been converted to Windows-form paths from the Unix/Linux-form paths that were provided.

If I run this directly on the command line, no exception is thrown and the Java application runs successfully:

```
$ docker run -it --rm -v /c/Users/jgagnon/devops/charts/helm/spoe:/tmp/inputs -v /c/Users/jgagnon/workspace/devops-util/java/helm-template-scanner:/tmp/outputs helm-template-scanner --source-dir=/tmp/inputs --dest-dir=/tmp/outputs --include-source
2023-01-09 13:28:18 INFO  Main:22 - Command line arguments:
2023-01-09 13:28:18 INFO  Main:23 - --source-dir=/tmp/inputs
2023-01-09 13:28:18 INFO  Main:23 - --dest-dir=/tmp/outputs
2023-01-09 13:28:18 INFO  Main:23 - --include-source
2023-01-09 13:28:19 INFO  Main:67 - BY DEFINITION
2023-01-09 13:28:19 INFO  Main:69 - definition: "common.affinities.nodes" [/tmp/inputs/charts/keycloak/charts/postgresql/charts/common/templates/_affinities.tpl:40]
2023-01-09 13:28:19 INFO  Main:69 -   file: /tmp/inputs/charts/keycloak/charts/postgresql/charts/common/templates/_affinities.tpl
2023-01-09 13:28:19 INFO  Main:69 -     lines:
2023-01-09 13:28:19 INFO  Main:69 -       38: {{ include "common.affinities.nodes" (dict "type" "soft" "key" "FOO" "values" (list "BAR" "BAZ")) -}}
...
```

What is happening here? How can I fix this?

Comment: (For the end user, would installing a JVM be easier than installing and configuring Docker?  That doesn't seem any more complex, and it would presumably avoid the problems you're describing here.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like MSYS is doing path conversion inside the docker container to be relative to the Git Bash install directory rather than the container filesystem root.

There are a few ways to prevent this behavior.

1. Use double forward slash "//" on paths inside the container on the docker run line. In your case change all uses of `/tmp/inputs` to `//tmp/inputs` and `/tmp/outputs` to `//tmp/outputs`
2. Another option is to execute docker with `winpty` in front of docker `winpty docker ...`
3. Set the special environment variable MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 which will prevent git bash from mangling the paths. (I personally prefer this option by setting this variable to be exported in my .bashrc file so that path conversion is always disabled.)

See https://gist.github.com/borekb/cb1536a3685ca6fc0ad9a028e6a959e3 for more info.